# Como evitar que um site seja listado no Google?

Tags: aplicação-web, google

Estou criando um site e um aplicativo que irá acessar a mesma base de dados. Enquanto ainda estarei desenvolvendo o site e todos os seus módulos, já irei colocando o mesmo "no ar". Até mesmo para testes mais eficientes.

Como posso fazer para que esse meu site não apareça em pesquisas do Google? Ou seja, quero que somente eu (ou quem souber do URL exata), possa acessar o mesmo. Mas de tal forma que pesquisando no Google pelo nome do site, ele não seja relacionado nas buscas.

Comment: Não seria melhor você usar um servidor local Apache? Isso garante que só você possa acessar o site e consequentemente dará mais segurança.

Comment: Eu vi que você está um pouco perdido para aceitar uma resposta, você só pode aceitar uma delas. É esta mesmo que você deseja aceitar? Votar você pode em todas. Veja o [tour].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Buscadores utilizam *web crawlers* para achar e indexar sites na web. Para previnir que o seu site seja indexado, uma alternativa é usando a metatag:

```
<meta name="robots" content="nofollow" />
```

No cabeçalho do seu HTML, afim de informar que a página não deve ser disponibilizada para o público.

Mas vale reforçar que esta metatag apenas informa os buscadores de que você não quer ser "encontrado". Ela **não bloqueia** o acesso ao seu site caso ele já esteja publicado em algum servidor externo. Qualquer pessoa que tiver o link direto continuaria podendo acessá-lo.

Answer (score 6):

Tem várias técnicas para resolver isto, cada uma com suas vantagens e desvantagens. Pela sua descrição basta usar o [`robots.txt`](http://www.robotstxt.org/) que é um arquivo que diz para os buscadores que você não quer que aquele conteúdo seja indexado por eles.

A presença deste arquivo não garante nada, mas os buscadores mais conhecidos respeitam isto. Se precisar de garantias, terá que usar um mecanismo de proteção exigindo pelo menos uma [autenticação básica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) antes da pessoas acessar.

É possível usar a técnica do `meta` colocada na outra resposta mas ela dá trabalho. Tem que colocar em todas as páginas, e se um dia precisam mudar isto no *site*, tem que mudar em todos arquivos. É possível dizer no `robots.txt` quais páginas serão afetadas e de uma forma centralizada. É muito melhor.

Em alguns casos pode ser melhor ou a única forma de fazer, mas raramente é o caso. Deve ser uma solução secundária. Ainda assim, é melhor fazer isto:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
```

Também é possível controlar isto no servidor HTTP. Mas são raros casos em que isto é mais interessante. Pode-se usar este elemento no cabeçalho do protocolo:

```
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).