# Indexação de sites pela metade é possível?

Tags: robots.txt, google

Ao navegar pela internet lendo artigos e mais artigos, me deparei com alguns que só são exibidos pela metade, ou só o início, [aqui vai um exemplo](https://www.devmedia.com.br/processo-de-modelagem-de-data-warehouse/32827). Nesse caso, só quem é assinante tem acesso liberado.

Minha dúvida é?

O site é totalmente indexado pelos motores de busca? Ou a página é indexada pela metade? o arquivo `robots.txt` tem relação com o fato?

Como é possível esse tipo de delimitação sobre o conteúdo de um site, no que se refere o que o leitor pode ou não ler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pergunta fala em duas coisas, indexação parcial do site e parcial da página.

Sim, você pode usar [`robots.txt` ou o `meta name="robots"`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78790/101) para indicar o que não quer que indexe.

Na verdade se o conteúdo for protegido de alguma outra forma contra acesso nem precisa disso. Se a página só é devidamente acessível mediante senha o conteúdo não será indexado.

Na verdade essa é a única forma efetiva de impedir a indexação, já que dizer que não quer algo indexado é apenas uma convenção. Um indexador pode não respeitar isso. Hoje o Google respeita, mas ele pode não respeitar quando ele quiser. Existem indexadores maliciosos.

Obviamente que só o controle do acesso feito no servidor terá efetividade.

Tudo isso é fato bem conhecido. Acho que a dúvida maior é a indexação parcial da página.

Isso geralmente é feito identificando que o cliente pedindo a página é um indexador. Ele gera uma página diferente com conteúdo parcial quando for um indexador conhecido. Obviamente que é possível enganar o site dizendo que é o indexador. Então o indexador recebe a página toda e pode indexar todo o conteúdo, mas um cliente normal recebe a página capada. Isso pode trazer penalidades na classificação da indexação se o mecanismo identificar a manobra. E claro que sempre será possível acessar o conteúdo pelo cache do indexador ou site que faça o mesmo que o indexador (ex.: outline.com).

Obviamente que você pode enviar todo o conteúdo e limitar via JavaScript. Isso protege nada, só engana, já que o conteúdo está lá. Pode dificultar para o leigo, mas não tem proteção.

Aproveito para dizer sobre o mito de que os indexadores executam JavaScript. Sim alguns executam, mas não todos. E eles não podem simular ações de usuário como um usuário real faz, então não conte com a indexação se houver interação com o usuário ou outra forma que dependa de coisas que o indexador não é capaz de fazer, e sempre aparecem novas coisas que o indexador não é capaz de simular. O código programático existe na página justamente para definir fluxos que não são padronizados e isto, por definição, torna impossível na prática tentar simular tudo o que pode ocorrer.

Se quer proteger o conteúdo, só controlando no servidor. E obviamente que controlará a exibição, não impede da pessoa copiar e postar em outro lugar, até mesmo de forma automática. É bom deixar claro porque algumas pessoas acham que papai noel existe.

Comment: Então, o que acontece de fato é a indexação completa pelos motores de busca, e através da lógica de programação por parte do servidor que faz o controle do que pode ou não ser visto pelos usuários. nesse caso o controle pode ser feito via javascript (escondendo o conteúdo) ou via php (alguma lógica funcionando no lado servidor) é isso?

Comment: É, mas como eu disse isso não protege de fato. Ou você protege ou você indexa, não tem como fazer os dois. Por isso eu coloquei a última frase..

Comment: Entendi, mas me ocorreu uma hipótese agora, imagine que um post de um artigo esteja dividido pela metade, então a primeira metade é postada e publicada e a outra não. (nesse caso não tem como indexar ja que não existe (ainda)), então o usuário loga e rapidamente o servidor enviar aquele trecho que estava faltando (segunda parte do post) , nesse caso hipotético não ocorreu a proteção e indexação juntos?

Comment: Não, só a proteção, a outra parte não está visível por ninguém, então não foi indexado. Se foi indexado pode ser visto pelo cache do indexador, então não está protegido.

Comment: Fantástico, valeu.

Answer (score 2):

Tomando o [Googlebot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googlebot) como exemplo...

Segundo [este artigo no kissmetrics](https://blog.kissmetrics.com/the-way-google-scans/), o crawler do Google indexa toda a página, incluindo título, descrição, o atributo `alt` das imagens e *todo o conteúdo*.

Segundo [este outro artigo, no Search Engine Land](https://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157), o Googlebot é ainda capaz de processar JavaScript a fim de indexar conteúdo incluído no DOM dinamicamente. [Este outro artigo](https://goralewicz.com/blog/javascript-seo-experiment/) mostra testes exaustivos de indexação de páginas que utilizam *frameworks* e bibliotecas JavaScript mais populares (spoiler: parece que ele ainda não processa AngularJS v2 muito bem. Justo o *framework* do próprio Google, vai entender...).

Como a indexação depende do crawler ser capaz de alcançar a página, o link para ela precisa existir em algum lugar na internet ou sua indexação deve ser explicitamente solicitada através das ferramentas de webmaster do Google.

Assim, se um *web crawler* for capaz de chegar a uma área de conteúdo restrito para indexá-la, então um ser humano também o é, e o conteúdo deixa de ser restrito. Para que uma área de conteúdo restrito seja eficiente, não deve haver links para ela que não sejam barrados por algum tipo de autenticação.

O arquivo [robots.txt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard) representa um mapa do que o webmaster deseja que seja ou não indexado por crawlers, como por exemplo:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /restrito/
```

Robôs das grandes empresas de busca tendem a obedecer tais diretrizes, mas deve-se lembrar que nem todo mundo respeita as regras e políticas de boa vizinhança. Se o conteúdo é restrito, exiba-o apenas sob autenticação.

Portanto, o Googlebot parece ser capaz de indexar todo o conteúdo de uma página, incluindo aquele "revelado" dinamicamente via JavaScript, *mas não o que estiver atrás de uma checagem de autenticação*, como seu exemplo de uma área de assinantes. Caso o webmaster desse artigo deseje que ele seja indexado sob termos que só estão no conteúdo restrito, deve copiá-los de alguma forma para a parte pública da página, como na forma de palavras-chave dentro da tag `<description>`.

Assim, finalmente respondendo a sua pergunta: **sim, é possível que sites sejam indexados "pela metade"**, pois *crawlers* só são capazes de indexar aquilo que eles conseguem acessar. Áreas restritas não são indexadas.

Comment: Tá, talvez eu tenha confundido JS em geral com essa nota sobre Ajax, mas fica o aviso de qualquer sorte: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

Comment: Aparentemente o Googlebot processa JS sim, ao menos [este outro artigo](https://goralewicz.com/blog/javascript-seo-experiment/) demonstra uns testes até quem bem completos em se tratando de frameworks e bibliotecas populares.  Vou incluir um exemplo de robots sim, valeu!

Comment: De fato, confundi com o anúncio sobre Ajax...

Comment: @nunks.lol se o arquivo robots.txt serve apenas como um aviso, não impedido de fato a indexação, (já que alguns rastradores podem não obdecer a política de boa vizinhança) então só é efetivo a restrição de conteúdo se houver uma lógica de programação no lado do servidor?

Comment: @JonathasB.Cavalcante Isso. Para garantir que ninguém vá indexar a área restrita de seu site você tem que incluir isso na sua lógica. Não é aconselhável confiar que o programador do *crawler* vai respeitar o robots.txt. O Google e a Microsoft dizem que respeitam, mas existe uma infinidade de outros *crawlers* e *web scrapers* individuais que podem não respeitar. Pense em *crawlers* como visitantes humanos potencialmente mal-intencionados: caso você dê uma brecha para acessar conteúdo restrito sem verificar se eles têm autorização, eles vão acessar esse conteúdo.

Comment: Entendi, agradeço a resposta. =)