# Conceito de bloqueio dos diretórios no robots.txt

Tags: seo, google

Tenho uma dúvida referente ao bloqueio de arquivos e diretórios através do robots.txt. A estrutura do meu site é composta por diretórios com arquivos backend (models, controllers e classes), **que são responsáveis por gerar o conteúdo**.

Segue a estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A navegação do usuário será sempre através do index.php, que vai acionar os arquivos de backend das outras pastas e gerar o conteúdo.

robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /admin/
Disallow: /.git/
Disallow: /project/
Disallow: /model/
Disallow: /objects/
Disallow: /controller/

Sitemap: https://www.detetiveparticularemsp.com.br/sitemap.xml
```

É necessário(sugerível) bloquear esses arquivos/pastas de processamento de conteúdo(backend) no robots, deixando disponivel apenas imagens, css e a index.php?

Comment: O que quer dizer com interpretado, pelo robots?

Comment: @MagicHat Interpretado pelos rastreadores que acessam o arquivo robots.txt

Comment: Nesse caso, vai depender da url de localização do  "conteúdo". É um tipo de esquema de diretórios, se barrar "/root", não tem nada para indexar dentro de "/root".

Comment: Você bloqueia tudo que não quer que seja rastreado, se /index gera o conteúdo e ele não está bloqueado, ele será indexado. O bloqueio informa para o rastreador que em determinado nível dos diretórios, nem precisa gastar recursos para verificar.

Comment: Seria interessante você adicionar o robots que está desenvolvendo.

Comment: @MagicHat então acho que seria viavel bloquear todas as pastas/arquivos, e inserir no robots apenas a permissão do index,imagens,css e js

Comment: Mas qual o sentido do rastreador indexar css, js... Eles tem conteúdo relevante?

Comment: Atenha-se ao objetivo do webcrawler, indexar `urls`, à partir do momento que o `url` é indexado, qualquer outro programa que tenha acesso a esse índice, terá um caminho otimizado para acessá-lo, o css e js serão usados normamente pelo recurso que o solicitou.

Comment: @MagicHat eu li alguns artigos que sugerem a liberação desses recursos para que os rastreadores consigam saber se o site é mobile-friendly Eu estou começando agora estudar sobre SEO, estou tentando filtrar essas informações que leio em alguns sites e blogs
https://yoast.com/dont-block-css-and-js-files/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No contexto de WebCrawler, o rastreador é um programa que envia requisições aos domínios com o objetivo de verificar, indexar e organizar os recursos disponíveis  para acesso futuro de forma otimizada.

Um dos motivos de ter um `robots` é evitar requisições desnecessárias a sua aplicação consumindo recursos.

Sempre que um determinado `url` é indexado ele será monitorado com uma determinada frequência consumindo recursos(de ambas as partes cliente(nesse caso o webcrawler) e servidor(nesse caso o ambiente da sua aplicação)) a cada vez que for solicitado.

Então, sim, é uma boa pratica você informar aos `webcrawlers` que existem recursos que não devem ser indexados.

O cliente nomeia um `User-agent`, que ao ter acesso a instrução `Disallow: /` de um `robots.txt`, entende que não deve indexar nada dentro desde diretório, entretanto, se em seguida houver uma instrução como  `Allow: /esse-sim` ele vai indexar.

Como dito nos comentários o `robots.txt` lê arquivos `.txt` afim de encontrar `urls` para fazerem parte do seu índice, quem usa o `css` é sua aplicação, quem usa o `js` é o navegador que também é um cliente como o webcrawler, mas é preparado para procurar por `js`, diferente do webcrawler que só quer as `urls`.

Veja, os `webcrawlers` são criados para diversas finalidades.

Quando você informa em um `robots.txt` uma instrução, não quer dizer que está "bloqueando acesso ao recurso", você está informando que ali, não tem nada relevante ao contexto que sua aplicação se propõe.

Isso quer dizer se um `chinaspider`, quiser ver se sua aplicação, contém alguma vulnerabilidade em `/wp-admin`, mesmo com uma instrução negando em um `robots.txt`, ainda assim ele poderá requisitar o recurso e indexar em seu prórprio índice.

No contexto do Google, ele possuí seus próprios [Users-agents](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=pt), para várias plataformas e finalidades, que devido aos seu propósito específico, deveriam agradecer aos serem informados da presença de recursos irrelevantes.

Answer (score 4):

[O `robot.txt` apenas impede o acesso do buscador (do Google) ao conteúdo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78790/101), não do navegador normal. E mesmo assim só se o buscador quiser fazer isto. Isto não é uma proteção universal, é um "acordo de cavalheiros", se está pensando nisto como proteção, esqueça.

O buscador irá ignorar tudo o que tem na pasta onde ter este arquivo e seguirá a instrução indicada dentro dele do que mais ignorar. Ou seja, você só usa isto em conteúdo que não quer que o buscador indexe. Isto quer dizer que você quis deixar este conteúdo público mas não quer que ele seja indexado. Só isto, não serve para mais nada.

Entenda que o que tem dentro da estrutura do seu site não é necessariamente acessado publicamente, pelo buscador, navegador ou outra coisa. Mas pode ser acessado se o conteúdo estiver público. O acesso se dará de acordo com alguns gatilhos, por exemplo ter um *link* para a página ali. Outro exemplo é ter um *sitemap* como fez. O maior motivo para ter um *sitemap* é querer que o conteúdo seja devidamente indexado, portanto colocar o `robots.txt` não faz o menor sentido, ou tem um ou tem o outro, eles se opõem.

Se o que deseja é não ter nada desses arquivos acessíveis então deve configurar o servidor HTTP de forma adequada para que esses arquivos não fiquem públicos, ou pelo menos que não possam ser lidos de forma direta e só possa ser executados. É comum que as pessoas usem configurações prontas que já resolvem isto. Se não sabe como fazer adequadamente então sugiro contratar um profissional para fazer isto para você.

Se tudo estiver configurado corretamente então seu site irá executar os arquivos `.php` internam ente no servidor e gerar um conteúdo externo enviado para quem requisitou. O arquivo não será lido de forma direta, ninguém pegará seu código (se tudo estiver configurado corretamente).

Como você colocou um `robots.txt` então pelo esta pasta não será lida (nem o `index.php` será chamado, seu site nunca será indexado. E como disse em comentários que só o `index.php` é acessado e que é um conteúdo que parece ser público, e ainda tem um `*sitemap*, a sugestão é só tirar o`robots,txt`, ele está impedindo o Google e outros buscadores de indexar seu conteúdo.

A impressão que dá é que está protegendo algumas pastas de não serem acessadas de forma algum com o `ronots.txt`, mas isto não acontece. A proteção se dá por configuração do servidor HTTP (Apache, IIS, etc.) e das permissões dadas aos arquivos e pastas na *filesystem* do sistema operacional.

Comment: Então, no caso é um website com um código que busca o conteúdo no banco de dados, isso para que facilite os ADM's a inserirem novos artigos ou atualizações.

Comment: @MarcusOliveira então o conteúdo é gerado no *backend*, estas pastas que citou só estão no *backend*, certo? Cai no que eu falei, o `robots.txt` nada tem a ver com isso e o acesso a isto não deveria ser acessado publicamente. Se está acessando tem algum outro problema.

Comment: @MarcusOliveira, não, seu comentário está totalmente equivocado.

Comment: @Maniero eu entendi sua resposta e me esclareceu quase que por completo a minha questão, que realmente pode não estar tão clara. Vou corrigir (editar) a pergunta para facilitar.
Eu não sei explicar com outras palavras, mas o meu projeto (site) possui apenas um arquivo "index.php", que é responsável por tratar qual caminho foi acessado pelo usuário e retornar o conteúdo adequando do banco de dados usando os arquivos e classes contidos nas pastas model,controller etc... Sendo assim, gostaria de saber se devo deixar diponivel no robots apenas o index e arquivos de estilo

Comment: @Maniero + ou tenho que deixar liberado também os arquivos de processamento de conteúdo

Comment: @Maniero com sua ultima resposta já ficou claro que devo deixar essas pastas bloqueadas no robots, pois o conteúdo é gerado pelos arquivos contidos nelas , certo ?

Comment: @MarcusOliveira se você quer realmente entender como isso funciona, não pule etapas no seu aprendizado, entenda o que realmente acontece, e não dependa de afirmações de terceiros. Edite sua questão, colocando os elementos necessários, incluindo possíveis exemplos no escopo da suas dúvidas de forma que uma questão se ligue a outra e ajude a melhorar a experiência de colaboração da comunidade, boa sorte ;)

Comment: @MagicHat desculpe, realmente não está completa. Vou editar especificando como o projeto está estruturado, assim acredito que vai facilitar para responderem

Comment: @MarcusOliveira não, não foi o que eu disse, muito pelo contrário, o que eu disse é que é irrelevante usar o `robots.txt`, se entendi bem o que está fazendo.